# function returns nothing, but I don't know where I did wrong

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    ord = len(aStr) -1
    high = ord
    low = 0
    num = (high + low) // 2
    def compare(num, char):
        nonlocal low
        if aStr[num] == char:
            return aStr[num] == char
        elif aStr[num] > char:
            high = num
            num = (high + low) // 2
            return compare(num, char)
        else:
            low = num
            num = (high + low) // 2
            return compare(num, char) 
    compare(num, char)

isIn('c', 'abcdefghijk')
```

I'm wondering why this code couldn't give me any result. I'm new to python. This is an assignment on an online course. Could anybody help me?

**Instruction from the professor:**
[image: instruction from the professor]

Comment: Why not debugging your code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to return a value, functions (defined with `def <function name>`) have to contain a `return` statement. `isIn` does not contain a return statement (except as part of `compare`, which doesn't count).

Additionally, I suspect you meant to unindent the last line - you intended to define `isIn` and then call it. Currently the last line is part of the definition of the `isIn` function, and so it won't get called as part of the script (unless you call it somewhere else).

By the way, please don't post screenshots of code, since they are difficult to test, are not compatible with screen readers, and the image host can go offline. See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)